# Logging to Azure Log Analytics custom fields using Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog, azure-log-analytics

I'm new to azure and also a rookie in .net, so this may be a noob question :)
Anyway, I have successfully managed to log to Azure Log Analytics using this code snippet:

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration().
            Enrich.WithExceptionDetails().
            Enrich.WithApplicationInformation(serviceName).
            MinimumLevel.Debug().
            MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information).
            Enrich.FromLogContext().
            Destructure.ByTransforming<ExpandoObject>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject).
            //Enrich.WithProperty("ErrorMsg_CF","test").
            WriteTo.AzureAnalytics(workspaceId: "MyWorkSpaceID", 
                                   authenticationId: "MyAuthID",
                                   logName: "MyCustomLog_CL",
                                   restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug)
```

And:

```
        Logging.Logger.Initialize(serviceName: "Logging Web Test v1.1");
        Logging.Logger.GetLogger().Log(LogLevel.Debug, "{ErrorMsg_CF}:{TraceID_CF}:{UserName_CF}", errorMsg,traceID,userName);
```

I have, in my Log Analytics custom log table, created 3 custom fields: "ErrorMsg_CF", "TraceID_CF" and "UserName_CF", and I want to either be able to directly log to these custom fields, or somehow split my errormsg into these three custom fields.

When I import a file, I see that the message is stored in the "RawData" field, and with that field I am able to use the custom field generator and create custom fields, and also let Log Analytics split the message into the fields for me. But, when I do it through my application, the message is stored in the "LogMEssage_s" field, and seems like it's not possible to create custom fields from that field.

So, anyone know how I can log to my custom fields from my application?

Comment: I'm running into this scenario as well, have you found a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The default formatting configuration is a line by line event logging. ALN can be ingested using JSON so that will be the best way to format log entry in that way.

```
.WriteTo.DESTINATION(new CompactJsonFormatter(), OTHER OPTIONS HERE)
```

[Serilog formatting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I don't really get it. WriteTo.AzureAnalytics() don't have a inparam for a CompactJsonFormatter (it does have a IFormatProvider as inparam though). Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: the IFormatProvider is the interface for the json or other formatter.

Comment: @jihonsvik - I am working on that as encountered same issue with my app :)